# libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is not permitted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an app which is made of 2 language combined - Objective-C and Swift

Now when I try to upload it on AppStore, It is giving me below error:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure

The binary file `MyApp.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

Please can any one tell me how to solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue, Did you get any solution ?